# How to write check box event

Tags: c#

I am using C#, using the string append to creating a check box. I want to create a function on selecting a check box.
`mStr.Append("<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Bike'>");` 
 code for creating check box. Can you help me to create function on check box event.

Comment: hi please , I do want to help you , but I don't know how to help you ! Say clearly what you need !

Comment: I assume you are doing web.retag it with javascript jquery.you can do it with javascript jquery. there are plenty of examples

Comment: You can add one more property for checkbox that is OnClick="funName()". you can create this function in javascript and write code to handle the event.